# How to get curl results as variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, variables, curl

With Powershell, I want to run the following command and store the `status_url` as a variable.  I am unable to reference the `status_url` directly though.

```
$upload = curl.exe -u username:password -i -F filedata=@filename.csv https://sitename.com/csv
```

`$upload` stores the following info:

PS C:\Scripts> $upload
HTTP/2 200 
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
content-security-policy: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://cdn.ravenjs.com https://cdn.mxpnl.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com http
s://*.googleapis.com https://cdn.segment.com https://d2yyd1h5u9mauk.cloudfront.net https://*.typeform.com;connect-src 'self' https://api.mixpanel.com https://web.delighted.com https://a
pi.segment.io;object-src 'self';style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://use.fontawesome.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.googleapis.com;font-src
 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://use.fontawesome.com https://fonts.gstatic.com;
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
referrer-policy: strict-origin
set-cookie: session=d9337cbf2c313e12_5c24fe8c.Bg33P1e8TOQs9sDCpRWwOoSDDao; Domain=.rolepoint-qa.com; Secure; HttpOnly; Path=/
x-cloud-trace-context: 2586e15ea742ba3202516d6c9c58d3d2;o=1
date: Thu, 27 Dec 2018 16:32:12 GMT
server: Google Frontend
content-length: 94
expires: Thu, 27 Dec 2018 16:32:12 GMT
cache-control: private

{"result": {"status_url": "https://sitename.com/csv/v1/status/1234567"}}

How can I just reference the `status_url` itself so I can use it in a GET to check the upload status?

The output is JSON, do I need to parse $upload or is there a way to reference `$upload.status_url`

Comment: ($upload | ConvertFrom-Json).result.status_url

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.. Getting this error                             PS C:\Scripts\rolepoint> ($upload|ConvertFrom-Json).result.status_url
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: HTTP.
At line:1 char:10
+ ($upload|ConvertFrom-Json).result.status_url
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Comment: Strange, this works `('{"result": {"status_url": "https://sitename.com/csv/v1/status/1234567"}}'|ConvertFrom-Json).result.status_url` here in PSv5.1

Comment: Can you check what type the $upload has ($upload.gettype())? Is it string or array?

Comment: PS > ($upload.gettype())

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                     
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                     
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

Comment: OK. Then add join, like ($upload -join "" | ConvertFrom-Json)

Comment: PS C:\Scripts> ($upload -join "" | ConvertFrom-Json).result.status_url
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: HTTP.
At line:1 char:21
+ ($upload -join "" | ConvertFrom-Json).result.status_url
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `($upload | ConvertFrom-Json).result.status_url` is not working because of -i parameter, it's mixing response body with headers, so you are not getting valid json. Is it OK to remove it? If you need to keep it then probably use Invoke-Webrequest instead. You can try the code below (I can't test it). If it's working then just browse $response object (response body will be in $response.Content).

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "yourpassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$user = "yourUser"

$params = @{ 
 Uri = "https://sitename.com/csv"
 InFile = "path/to/your/file.csv"
 Method = "Post"
 Credential = [PSCredential]::new($user, $password)
 }

$response = Invoke-Webrequest @params
```

You can also try extract that url with regexp from that mixed response, something like:

```
$Upload -match 'https://sitename.com/csv/v1/status/\d*'
$Matches[0]
```

Comment: removing the -i in the curl.exe command did the trick!                               
$status_url = ($upload|ConvertFrom-Json).result.status_url contains just the status url now.